# Writing OWLObjectPropertyExpression on OWL Ontology using OWL API

Tags: java, semantic-web, owl, owl-api

I'm trying to write an OWLObjectPropertyExpression on OWL Ontology object. If I had an OWL Class I use something like the following:

```
 OWLOntologyManager managerWriter = OWLManager.createOWLOntologyManager();
 OWLOntology ontoWrite=managerWriter.createOntology();
 OWLDataFactory factory = manager.getOWLDataFactory();
 managerWriter.addAxiom(ontoWrite,factory.getOWLDeclarationAxiom(factory.getOWLClass((cl.getIRI()))));
```

But what  should I write if I want to write an OWLObjectPropertyExpression ?
Thanks in advance !.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code snippet illustrate an example of usage and creation of an OWL expression using the OWL API (taken and adapted from [there](https://code.google.com/p/elk-reasoner/wiki/QueryingComplexClasses)):

```
//OWL Expression we would like to create:
//in OWL Functional syntax: ObjectIntersectionOf(A ObjectSomeValuesFrom(R B))
//in Manchester syntax: A and R some B
PrefixManager pm = new DefaultPrefixManager("http://example.org/");
OWLClass A = factory.getOWLClass(":A", pm);
OWLObjectProperty R = factory.getOWLObjectProperty(":R", pm);
OWLClass B = factory.getOWLClass(":B", pm);

//The expression
OWLClassExpression expression = 
  factory.getOWLObjectIntersectionOf(A, factory.getOWLObjectSomeValuesFrom(R, B));

//Create a class in order to use the expression
OWLClass C = factory.getOWLClass(":C", pm);

// Declare an equivalentClass axiom
//Just there to show how an example on how to use the expression
OWLAxiom definition = factory.getOWLEquivalentClassesAxiom(C, expression);
manager.addAxiom(ontology, definition);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In my case, I receive an OWLClassExpression object from an external object and I don't know  what to put in OWLAxiom definition. Any suggestions ?

Comment: What are you trying to do with the OWLClassExpression object? Usually people are using such expressions in combination with axioms as illustrated here.

Comment: Well, let me explain further. I'm using Hermit Reasoner in an experimental way. In the reasoner exists a class, org.semanticweb.Hermit.structural.OWLAxioms . I'm trying to write in an ontology some of its fields ( for example  m_complexObjectPropertyExpressions ).

Comment: hum, not sure I can help more than with the answer I've provided, sorry :-/

Comment: I just forgot that I can't add an  Expression in an ontology since it's not included in some axiom.

Comment: Glad you figured it out :-)